# Using Swift Collection Type to parse JSON

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing

I created an UITableview to add the repository's names from a github user. This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        var gits:[String] = []

        lazy var tableView:UITableView = {
            let tb = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .Grouped)
            tb.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth]
            tb.delegate = self
            tb.dataSource = self
            tb.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"cell")
            return tb
        }()

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.gits.count
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            let repoName = self.gits[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = repoName
            return cell
        }

        let jsonParser:(data:NSData)->[String] = {(data:NSData)->[String] in
            var result:[String]=[]
            do {
               let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
                for git in json as! NSArray {
                    result.append(git["full_name"] as! String)
                }
            } catch {

            }
            return result
        }

        func connectToServer(){
            let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/gazolla/repos")
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
            let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil){
                    print("\(error)")
                    return
                }
                self.gits = self.jsonParser(data: data!)
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                     self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
            self.connectToServer()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
    }
```

When I was writing the json parser, I used NSArray  to loop through json and use force cast to get a String with repository's name. Like his:

```
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
        for git in json as! NSArray {
            result.append(git["full_name"] as! String)
        }
```

I would like to use swift collections to do this, but I couldn't figure out what data types I should use in Array.

The Json structure return from github is like this:

[image]

Which type can use in Swift Array to replace NSArray to parse this json file?

Comment: Have you tried `[AnyObject]` or `[String: AnyObject]`?

Comment: Hi Eendje, [AnyObject] works fine ! Thanks !